# Haskell print the first line into Browser Tab

Tags: html, haskell, converters

Just a simple question, my code is complete. It takes an input file, breaks it into lines, reads the file line by line, does the conversions, which is in this case, turns certain things into HTML format (ex: #This is a line into a line with H1 HTML tags, formatting it into a header). The only thing I have left is to take the First line of code, and print that code into the browser tab. Also, the body, or tail must be printed into the window, not the tab. So the first line of my .txt file is The Title! which I want to show in the tab of the web browser. Here is something I have for that:

```
  formatToHTML :: String -> String
  formatToHTML [] = []
  formatToHTML x
          | head x    == --any char     = "<title>" ++ head ++ "</title>"
          | tail x    == --rest of file = "<body>"  ++ tail ++ "</tail>"
          | otherwise                   = null
```

or

```
   formatToHTML :: [String] -> String
   formatToHTML = unlines. map (show) "<title>" ++ head ++ </title>" $ lines
```

I dont want to, or I think even need to use guards here, but I cant think of a shorter way to do my task.

I would call this from my main method before I output my file to html.
Also, I know its a amateur haskell question. but how would I represent any char. Say, I want to say, if the head of x exists, print the head with the title tags. print tail with body tags. Help? Thank You

Comment: I think the signature should be `formatToHTML :: [String] -> String`

Comment: okay, could I possibly use that and write something like... see edits

Answer (score 1):

My guess of what you want is:

```
formatHtml :: [String] -> String
formatHtml [] = ""
formatHtml (x:xs) = unlines theLines
  where theLines = [ "<title>" ++ ...convert x to html... ++ "</title>",
                     "<body>" ] ++ map toHtml xs ++ [ "</body>" ]
        toHtml :: String -> String
        toHmtl str = ...converts str to HTML...
```

Example:

```
formatHtml [ "the title", "body line 1", "body line2" ]
```

results in:

```
<title>the title</title>
<body>
body line 1
body line 2
</body>
```

You still have to define the `toHtml` function and decide how to convert the first line to the inner html of the  tag.